# Chrome Extension to inject dynamic script into header and after opening body tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome extension that would 
I am trying to inject a bit of dynamic javascript into both the
a) the header of a page
b) The body of a page
however this should be added on page load
I am struggling with the existing documentation.

Any good guidance on how to get this done simply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Jquery Solution

Keep in mind that if you are adding this javascript *on page load*, the user will see a brief flash of original content before it's changed/updated by your script.

To add a console.log to both head and body in jquery:

**Adding to head**

```
$('head').append('<script>console.log("Script added to head")</script>');
```

**Adding to body**

```
$('body').append('<script>console.log("Script added to body")</script>');
```

**Verification**

If you add both of these to your chrome console, you should see something like:

```
Script added to head
Script added to body
```

If you search the HTML (Jquery's `$('html').html()`) for this script, you get two hits:

```
> regex = new RegExp(/<script>console\.log\("Script added to \w*?"\)<\/script>/, "g")
> pagetext = $('html').html().match(regex).length
2
```

As we added 2 lines console log "Script was added to ...", we have confirmation that the lines were added.

### When to load

If this is in your content script, you don't need to worry about nesting this in a [window.onload or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) if you have `"run_at": "document_end"` in your `manifest.json` (in the content script JSON).